# Wrong date and time in NSDateDormatter

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to create `NSDate` from two `NSStrings` which represent time and date.

Look at my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[form setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd.MM.yyyy"];

NSDate *notDate = [form dateFromString:[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@",z.time,z.date]];

NSLog(@"%@ // %@",[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@",z.time,z.date],notDate);
```

Log show me this numbers:

```
12:00 12.05.2013 // 2013-05-11 18:00:00 +0000
```

On the left side - 2 strings, on the right - date

First got 12:00, when second with 18:00! Besides, they got different days!

Why they are different?

Comment: Ever heard of a "time zone"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change

```
[form setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd.MM.yyyy"];
```

to

```
[form setDateFormat:@"HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy"];
```

it will use the 24 hour format.

```
NSLog(@"%@ // %@",[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@",z.time,z.date],notDate);
```

should output `00:00 12.05.2013 // 2013-05-11 18:00:00 +0000` and that explains everything:

The NSDateFormatter takes your current locale in account if you dont manually change it, while internally every NSDate object is saved in GMT (hence the `+0000`).
According to your profile you are located in Perm — that is 6 hours ahead of GMT.

So the dates are the same, once printed with the timezone in account, once without.

Answer (score 1):

You should change notDate into NSString via using stringFromDate function.  Try this code :-

```
NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[form setDateFormat:@"HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy"];

NSDate *notDate = [form dateFromString:[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@",z.time,z.date]];

NSLog(@"notDate =====> %@",notDate);

NSLog(@"date =====> %@",[form stringFromDate:notDate]);
```

I hope it helps you. Thanks

Comment: you can use hh:mm dd.MM.yyyy date format too for it. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSLog(@"%@ // %@",[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@",z.time,z.date],notDate);
```

In this line your printing a string and NSDate.. Your creating a NSDate from string. NSDate implicitly convert your string to NSDate format.... So they are different..

Comment: what? do you see that they got different hours and days?